# How do I anchor my Horizontal Scrollbar to the top of the JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I would like to move the Horizontal scroll bar to the top of my JScrollPane. Does anyone knows how to do this ? I am on Java swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the `JScrollPane` API.

At the right of the first page you will see a simple diagram showing the layout of the scroll pane. You will see:

1. positions for the horizontal (and vertical) scrollbars
2. a location titled the "column header"

So what you need to do is move the horizontal scrollbar to the column header. To this you need to:

1. get a reference to the horizontal scrollbar. Read the API for the appropriate "getter" method
2. set the scrollbar to the column header. Read the API for the appropriate "setter" method.

Comment: Found it ! Thanks for the hunch !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
jScrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(jScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar());
```